# SQL server when try to access udf function created with dbo "Invalid object name 'dbo.Function_Client'."

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

Hi I have created an udf function  in sqlserver 2008...
when i try to access that it gives an error
"Invalid object name 'dbo.Function_Client"
I want to return the count of records from table and assign it to variable to return...so its a scalar function... inside i have implemented if else logic..

my udf below

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[Function_Clients] (@ClientAlias varchar(10) ,
  @TimePeriod int, @TypeOfTimePeriod varchar(1))

RETURNS INT
AS
BEGIN
  DECLARE @COUNT INT;

  IF(@ClientAlias='AEP' AND @TypeOfTimePeriod ='M')
     Set @COUNT =  (SELECT DISTINCT COUNT(*) AS 'NO_AEP' from dbo.Engagement INNER JOIN
        dbo.Client ON dbo.Engagement.ClientIdentifier = dbo.Client.ClientIdentifier 
    WHERE (dbo.ClientInvolvementRole.ClientInvolvementID = '1356790AERTY') 
    AND (CONVERT(datetime, dbo.Engagement.EndDate, 103) 
    <= CONVERT(datetime, DATEADD(MONTH, @TimePeriod , GETDATE()), 103))  


ELSE

---SAME ABOVE CODE BUT REPLACING MONTH WITH DAY AS 
---"DATEADD(DAY,@TimePeriod , GETDATE()), 103)" IN WHERE CONDITION  .

...if else (for various client alias)

RETURN @COUNT;  
END
GO
```

for each @clientalias i want to add  month part and  part based on my input in the @TypeOfTimePeriod .
For example @TypeOfTimePeriod ='M' means month or 'D' means its day to add in the dateadd part.

i have called like this select * from dbo.Clients('AEP',12,'M')

but its showing error
Invalid object name 'dbo.Function_NoOfClients'.

i can able to access the view with dbo.view1... but not this udf...
any problem in my udf..please help me...

Comment: In addition to the difference between `SELECT dbo.func()` and `SELECT * FROM dbo.func()` that Oleg pointed out, have you considered consolidating some of this logic? E.g. you have two queries when you could have simply calculated the end date in advance or used a `CASE` expression. Also is `dbo.Engagement.EndDate` a `DATETIME` or character data type?

Comment: A couple of other comments: what do you think `SELECT DISTINCT COUNT(*)` does differently from `SELECT COUNT(*)`? Why do you reference `dbo.ClientInvolvementRole` in the `WHERE` clause when it isn't part of the query? How is it possible that this function gets parsed and created correctly?

Comment: @Aaron  Its some typo that instead of client.ClientInvolvementID I put this ClientInvolvementRole.. and for your second question yest its datetime

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use

```
SELECT dbo.Clients('AEP',12,'M')
```

Note difference in usage of [Table valued and scalar functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-en/library/ms186755.aspx)